# How to find if items in 2 list match (but can't use direct equality)

Tags: optimization, flutter, dart, big-o

I have this code here, to see if the items in both lists are identical:

```
for (final car in this.cars) {
      bool found = false;
      for (final car2 in garage2.cars) {
        if (car2.id == car.id) {
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!found) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
}
```

(I previously check if the 2 list lengths are equal). Is there a way to rewrite that so that I don't have O(n2) complexity?

Comment: sort each list by id , then compare in only one for loop

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can override quals and hashcode methods for class Car
something like this

```
class Car {
  int id;
  // other fields

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object o) => o is Car && id == o.id;

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}
```

and then you can use the native method [listEquals](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/listEquals.html), which compares for deep equality.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

bool isEqual = listEquals<Car>(cars, garage2.cars);
```